# What are the differences between the 138min and 131min versions of Christiane F.?

Tags: alternate-version, christiane-f

Recently I realized that there are some differences in the runtime of Christiane F.

In IMDB there are two runtimes. One is 138min and another is 131min. And they said that the 131min version is a 'Cut' version.

I watched the 131min runtime version but I didn't see the 138min version. I had searched about the 138min runtime version, but I can't find anything (a file or just what the differences are).

Why are they different and what are they different for? What are the scenes that were cut?
I'm so curious. Please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

I just did some searches in German and found no definitive information but claims that the German TV version had cuts, not of sex scenes but of graphic depiction of drug withdrawal. According to Wikipedia, the US/UK cinematic version had 4 minutes cut, which would make its runtime 134 minutes. Then again, I also found numbers for the runtime of 124, 136 and 137 minutes. Finally, differences in runtime of TV versions might be due to [PAL Speedup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/576i#PAL_speed-up) rather than cuts.

Recent DVD releases are supposed to be uncut.